# How to get around the memory leak in the .NET Webbrowser control?

Tags: .net, memory, memory-leaks, browser, webbrowser-control

This is a widely-known, old issue with the .NET Webbrowser control.

Summary: Having the .NET webbrowser control Navigate to a page increases memory usage that is never freed.

Reproduce the memory leak: Add a WebBrowser control to a form. Use it to Navigate to whatever pages you'd like. about:blank works, scrolling down on Google Images until your usage is 100MB+ and then browsing elsewhere to notice barely any of that memory is freed is a more dramatic demonstration.

My current requirements for an application include running it for long periods of time, displaying a limited IE7 browser window. Running IE7 itself with some bastard setup of hooks, BHOs and group policies isn't desired either, although that's looking like the fallback at this time. 
Embedding a browser into a Windows Forms application is.
Using a different browser base is not an available option for me. IE7 is required.

Previous threads and articles relating to this known memory leak:

- http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=644658
- [How to Fix the Memory Leak in IE WebBrowser Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904478/how-to-fix-the-memory-leak-in-ie-webbrowser-control)
- [Memory leak when using WPF WebBrowser control in multiple windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069314/memory-leak-when-using-wpf-webbrowser-control-in-multiple-windows)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/88c21427-e765-46e8-833d-6021ef79e0c8/
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/8a2efea4-5e75-4e3d-856f-b09a4e215ede
- http://dotnetforum.net/topic/17400-appdomain-webbrowser-memory-leak/

Often-proposed fixes that DO NOT WORK:

- Going to different pages does not matter. about:blank triggers the leak. It does not require a page to have javascript, or any other extra technology.
- Using different versions of Internet Explorer does not matter. 7, 8, and 9 all exhibit the same symptoms, and as far as I've heard, all versions have the same memory leak in the control.
- Dispose()ing of the control does not help.
- Garbage Collecting does not help. (In fact, research I've done into this indicates the leak is in unmanaged COM code that the Webbrowswer control wraps.)
- Minimizing and setting process available memory to -1, -1(SetProcessWorkingSetSize() or simimlar.) only reduces physical memory usage, has no impact on virtual memory.
- Calling WebBrowser.Stop() is not a solution, and breaks functionality for using anything but static webpages, without doing more than just minimizing the leak slightly.
- Forcing a wait for a document to load completely before Navigating to another also doesn't help.
- Loading the control in a separate appDomain does not fix the issue. (I've not done this myself, but research shows others having no success with this route.)
- Using a different wrapper such as csexwb2 does not help, as this also suffers from the same issue.
- Clearing the Temporary Internet Files cache does nothing. The problem is in active memory, not on disk.

Memory is cleared when the entire application is closed and restarted.

I'm willing to write my own browser control in COM or Windows API directly, if that's a for-sure fix to the problem. Of course, I would prefer a less complicated fix; I'd rather avoid going down to lower levels to do things, because I don't want to be reinventing the wheel in terms of supported features of a browser. Letalone duplicating IE7 features and nonstandard behaviours in a roll-your-own style browser.

Help?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to launch the browser part in another application and communicate with it via .Net remoting or WCF or something of that nature? You could monitor the memory usage and then close and relaunch it when it hit some threshold.

Comment: @pstrjds: I think that's the only actual workaround which will be a huge pain to implement and will definitelly limit functionality.

Comment: It is a common misconception that releasing memory will instantly shrink the VM size of a process.  That's not how the Windows memory manager works.

Comment: @HansPassant: If what you mean is that the memory could be released by Windows later like if there wouldn't be a leak at all, then applications wouldn't get Out Of Memory exceptions or crash because of this. I've also tried most of the workarounds mentioned by the OP and my actual way of measuring the memory consumption is seeing the application crash.

Comment: @pstrjds: Wouldn't really do much for me in my use case. At the moment, the "best" workaround is minimizing the issue slightly by paging to disk constantly(Which does nothing but pretty it up a bit in Task Manager, although supposedly it makes the GC potentially more likely to collect things?), and explicitly calling the GC, and providing a quick-application-restart function to the users. This control seems pretty broken. What I'm currently investigating as a solution is using IE itself, and writing a/several BHO plugins to restrict/provide the required functionality for the application.

Comment: IExplore.exe (99% of it is implemented in a DLL which is the one used by the WebBrowser COM control) also behaves like that, it keeps at least ~50Mb private bytes allocated. I don't think it's related to .NET specifically. And I don't think it's a "memory leak" (except from many people's point of view because they don't like it). It's doubtful this can be changed by any means. BTW my FF process stays at 130M, and although I have only one tab opened only in Chrome, I have 3 chrome.exe processes for a total of ~200M.

Answer (score 13):

This leak appears to be a leak in unmanaged memory, so nothing you do in your process is going to reclaim that memory. From your post I can see that you've tried avoid the leak quite extensively and without success.

I would suggest a different approach if feasible. Create a separate application that uses web browser control and start it from your application. Use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608130/how-to-embed-window-from-another-application-in-our-wpf-window-as-user-control)  to embed newly created application within your own existing application. Communicate with that application using WCF or .NET remoting. Restart the child process from time to time to prevent it from taking to much memory.

This of course is quite complicated solution and the restart process could probably look ugly. You might maybe resort to restarting the whole browser application every time user navigates to another page.

Comment: @Doc, is the `WebBrowser` control a part of the UI? Or is it being hiddenly used for web automation?

Comment: @Noseratio In my case it's part of the UI.

Comment: Watching perfmon I saw that the IE 11 browser does something similar (probably for different reasons). It appeared to create a new process, move state to that process, then destroy the original process. We "fixed" this leak by a similar technique.

Answer (score 8):

I took the *udione*'s code (it worked for me, thanks!) and changed two small things:

1. **IKeyboardInputSite** is a public interface and has method **Unregister()**, so we don't need to use reflection after we received a reference to *_keyboardInputSinkChildren* collection.
2. As view not always has a direct reference to its window class (especially in MVVM) I added a method **GetWindowElement(DependencyObject element)** which returns the required reference by traversing through visual tree.

Thanks, udione

```
public void Dispose()
{
    _browser.Dispose();

    var window = GetWindowElement(_browser);

    if (window == null)
        return;

    var field = typeof(Window).GetField("_swh", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    var valueSwh = field.GetValue(window);
    var valueSourceWindow = valueSwh.GetType().GetField("_sourceWindow", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(valueSwh);
    var valuekeyboardInput = valueSourceWindow.GetType().GetField("_keyboardInputSinkChildren", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(valueSourceWindow);

    var inputSites = valuekeyboardInput as IEnumerable<IKeyboardInputSite>;

    if (inputSites == null)
        return;

    var currentSite = inputSites.FirstOrDefault(s => ReferenceEquals(s.Sink, _browser));

    if (currentSite != null)
        currentSite.Unregister();
}

private static Window GetWindowElement(DependencyObject element)
{
    while (element != null && !(element is Window))
    {
        element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
    }

    return element as Window;
}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: i tried to convert this to VB, but i am having some trouble; here is my GetWindowElement code: ` Private Shared Function GetWindowElement(element As System.Windows.DependencyObject) As System.Windows.Window While element IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not (TypeOf element Is System.Windows.Window) element = Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) End While Return TryCast(element, System.Windows.Window) End Function ` but in the dispose code, i am getting an error from this line: `Dim window = GetWindowElement(wbDebugMain)` saying the type is wrong.

Comment: actually, the specific error is

`Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.DependencyObject'.`

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to do clear memory leaks by using reflection and removing references from private fields on mainForm. This is not a good solution but for desperate people here is the code:

```
//dispose to clear most of the references
this.webbrowser.Dispose();
BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(this.webbrowser);

//using reflection to remove one reference that was not removed with the dispose 
var field = typeof(System.Windows.Window).GetField("_swh", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

var valueSwh = field.GetValue(mainwindow);

var valueSourceWindow = valueSwh.GetType().GetField("_sourceWindow", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(valueSwh);

var valuekeyboardInput = valueSourceWindow.GetType().GetField("_keyboardInputSinkChildren", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(valueSourceWindow);

System.Collections.IList ilist = valuekeyboardInput as System.Collections.IList;

lock(ilist)
{
    for (int i = ilist.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var entry = ilist[i];
        var sinkObject = entry.GetType().GetField("_sink", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(sinkObject.GetValue(entry), this.webbrowser.webBrowser))
        {
            ilist.Remove(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be the same solution as in this WPF forum thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/368755dd-0047-4a88-9951-ba0539266410

Comment: This actually works. Anyone care to explain this black magic? @___@

Comment: @udione, what to do for WinForm application?

Comment: How to do the same in WinForms?

Answer (score 3):

Having battled this exact **Out of Memory** issue from different directions (*Win32 WorkingSet / COM SHDocVw interfaces, etc.*) with the [WPF `WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) component, I discovered the problem for us was **jqGrid** plugin holding onto unmanaged resources in the IE `ActiveXHost` and not releasing them after calling `WebBrowser.Dispose()`. This issue is often created by Javascript that is not behaving properly. The odd thing is that the Javascript works fine in regular IE - just not from within the `WebBrowser` control. I surmise that the garbage collection is different between the two integration points as IE can never really be closed.

One thing I'd suggest if you are authoring the source pages is to remove all JS components and slowly adding them back in. Once you identify the offending JS plugin (*like we did*) - it should be easy to remedy the problem. In our case we just used [`$("#jqgrid").jqGrid('GridDestroy')`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods&s%5B%5D=griddestroy#add_on_grid_methods) to properly remove the events and associated DOM elements it created. This took care of the issue for us by invoking this when the browser is closed via [`WebBrowser.InvokeScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132.aspx).

If you don't have the ability to modify the source pages you navigate to - you would have to inject some JS into the page to clean up the DOM events and elements that are leaking memory. It would be nice if Microsoft found a resolution to this, but for now we are left probing for JS plugins that need **cleansed**.

Comment: This is years later, and I've not worked on the problem software for years as well(we never got it fixed, just crappy workarounds), but this response is incorrect, as the issue occurs with about:blank, meaning content of pages is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question has gone unanswered for a long time now. So many threads with the same question but not conclusive answer.

I have found a work around for this issue and wanted to share with you all who are still facing this issue.

step1: Create a new form say form2 and add a web-browser control on it.
step2: In the form1 where you have your webbrowser control, just remove it.
step3: Now, go to Form2 and make the access modifier for this webbrowser control to be public so that it can be accessed in Form1
step4: Create a panel in form1 and create object of form2 and add this into panel.
                Form2 frm = new Form2 ();
                frm.TopLevel = false;
                frm.Show();
                panel1.Controls.Add(frm); 
step5: Call the below code at regular intervals
                frm.Controls.Remove(frm.webBrowser1);
                frm.Dispose();

Thats it. Now when you run it, you can see that webbrowser control loaded and it will get disposed at regular intervals and there is no more hanging of the application.

You can add the below code to make it more efficient.

```
        IntPtr pHandle = GetCurrentProcess();
        SetProcessWorkingSetSize(pHandle, -1, -1);


        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
```

Comment: Setting MaxWorkingSet would (at best) just end up paging the memory out to disk, slowing performance and improving nothing

Answer (score 1):

The below solution worked for me:

```
Protected Sub disposeBrowers()
    If debug Then debugTrace()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New simple(AddressOf disposeBrowers))
    Else
        Dim webCliffNavigate As String = webCliff.Url.AbsoluteUri
        Me.DollarLogoutSub()
        If dollarLoggedIn Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Dim webdollarNavigate As String = webDollar.Url.AbsoluteUri
        Me.splContainerMain.SuspendLayout()
        Me.splCliffDwellers.Panel2.Controls.Remove(webCliff)
        Me.splDollars.Panel2.Controls.Remove(webDollar)
        RemoveHandler webCliff.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf webCliff_DocumentCompleted
        RemoveHandler webDollar.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf webDollar_DocumentCompleted
        RemoveHandler webCliff.GotFocus, AddressOf setDisposeEvent
        RemoveHandler webCliff.LostFocus, AddressOf setDisposeEvent
        RemoveHandler webDollar.GotFocus, AddressOf setDisposeEvent
        RemoveHandler webDollar.LostFocus, AddressOf setDisposeEvent
        webCliff.Stop()
        webDollar.Stop()

        Dim tmpWeb As SHDocVw.WebBrowser = webCliff.ActiveXInstance
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(tmpWeb)
        webCliff.Dispose()

        tmpWeb = webDollar.ActiveXInstance
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(tmpWeb)
        webDollar.Dispose()
        tmpWeb = Nothing

        webCliff = Nothing
        webDollar = Nothing
        GC.AddMemoryPressure(50000)
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete()
        GC.Collect()
        GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(50000)
        webCliff = New WebBrowser()
        webDollar = New WebBrowser()
        webCliff.CausesValidation = False
        webCliff.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        webDollar.CausesValidation = webCliff.CausesValidation
        webDollar.Dock = webCliff.Dock
        webDollar.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
        webDollar.Visible = True
        webCliff.Visible = True
        Me.splCliffDwellers.Panel2.Controls.Add(webCliff)
        Me.splDollars.Panel2.Controls.Add(webDollar)
        Me.splContainerMain.ResumeLayout()

        'AddHandler webCliff.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf webCliff_DocumentCompleted
        'AddHandler webDollar.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf webDollar_DocumentCompleted
        'AddHandler webCliff.GotFocus, AddressOf setDisposeEvent
        'AddHandler webCliff.LostFocus, AddressOf setDisposeEvent
        'AddHandler webDollar.GotFocus, AddressOf setDisposeEvent
        'AddHandler webDollar.LostFocus, AddressOf setDisposeEvent

        webCliff.Navigate(webCliffNavigate)
        disposeOfBrowsers = Now.AddMinutes(20)
    End If
End Sub
```

Best of luck,
Layla

Comment: i tried to implement this solution (although i only need to dispose of 1 webbrowser as opposed to 2) but i was getting a runtime error from this line: `Dim tmpWeb As WebBrowser = wbDebugMain.ActiveXInstance` The error message was `Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser'. Instances that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.` Any ideas?

Comment: btw, my System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser object is called 'wbDebugMain'

Comment: I was able to get around the error by declaring it as an "Object" instead of "WebBrowser"   (what is "SHDocVw.WebBrowser" ?) But memory was not released when i destroyed the controls and removed them from the form... I set them to get recreated every 10 mins, but memory still gradually rose, until i got an out of memory exception. I analyzed my memory leak with debugdiag and it said that jscript.dll was responsible for over a gig of memory allocations, yow! Maybe there are multiple different sorts of leaks? I seem to manage OK, unless there is javascript on the site...

Answer (score 0):

Believe its more of an .Net Framework issue rather than Web Browser control. Hooking to the navigated event of the browser with a handler which will dispose the browser and then navigating to about:blank will be a good workaround. For example:

```
private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var browser = (WebBrowser) _stackPanel.Children[_stackPanel.Children.Count - 1];
  _stackPanel.Children.RemoveAt(_stackPanel.Children.Count-1);

  NavigatedEventHandler dispose = null;
  dispose = (o, args) =>
  {
    browser.Navigated -= dispose;
    browser.Dispose();
  };
  browser.Navigated += dispose;
  browser.Navigate(new Uri("about:blank"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS WORKS, especially if yours is a Winforms application! Handles will be released immediately after closing the webbrowser.

USE CODE:

```
using system.windows.forms;
[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "SetProcessWorkingSetSize", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
internal static extern bool SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr pProcess, int dwMinimumWorkingSetSize, int dwMaximumWorkingSetSize);

[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentProcess", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
internal static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

// **Release handles invoking the above**
IntPtr pHandle = GetCurrentProcess();
SetProcessWorkingSetSize(pHandle, -1, -1);
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score -3):

Try this solution, i know its not ideal. Paste the code after each page load

```
System.Diagnostics.Process loProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
try
{
     loProcess.MaxWorkingSet = (IntPtr)((int)loProcess.MaxWorkingSet - 1);
     loProcess.MinWorkingSet = (IntPtr)((int)loProcess.MinWorkingSet - 1);
}
catch (System.Exception)
{

     loProcess.MaxWorkingSet = (IntPtr)((int)1413120);
     loProcess.MinWorkingSet = (IntPtr)((int)204800);
}
```

Comment: You really need to explain this (where did the magic numbers come from?)

Comment: Setting MaxWorkingSet would (at best) just end up paging the memory out to disk, slowing performance and improving nothing.