# Regarding udione's solution to the WebBrowser memory leak

Tags: .net, wpf, memory, browser, memory-leaks

This code was [given by udione in response to the perennial question about the memory leak in the WebBrowser control in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9351886/175679).

```cs
//dispose to clear most of the references 
this.webbrowser.Dispose(); 
BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(this.webbrowser); 

//using reflection to remove one reference that was not removed with the dispose  
var field = typeof(System.Windows.Window).GetField("_swh", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance); 

var valueSwh = field.GetValue(mainwindow); 

var valueSourceWindow = valueSwh.GetType().GetField("_sourceWindow", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(valueSwh); 

var valuekeyboardInput = valueSourceWindow.GetType().GetField("_keyboardInputSinkChildren", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(valueSourceWindow); 

System.Collections.IList ilist = valuekeyboardInput as System.Collections.IList; 

lock(ilist) 
{ 
    for (int i = ilist.Count-1; i >= 0; i--) 
    { 
        var entry = ilist[i]; 
        var sinkObject = entry.GetType().GetField("_sink", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance); 
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(sinkObject.GetValue(entry), this.webbrowser.webBrowser)) 
        { 
            ilist.Remove(entry); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

1) That third line,

```cs
BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(this.webbrowser);
```

won't compile for me. What is the type of `this.webbrowser`? I had assumed it was `WebBrowser`, but the method requires `System.Windows.DependencyObject`.

2) In the line

```cs
var valueSwh = field.GetValue(mainwindow);
```

what is `mainwindow`? The form holding the browser control?

3) In the sixth line from the bottom,

```cs
if (object.ReferenceEquals(sinkObject.GetValue(entry), this.webbrowser.webBrowser))
```

what is the type of `this.webbrowser.webBrowser`? I see no field called `webBrowser` in the `WebBrowser` type. Is this just a typo?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

1. [`BindingOperations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.aspx) is for WPF - you won't need this line if you are using WinForms.
2. To get the `mainwindow`, you just need to call the WPF method [`GetWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.getwindow.aspx).

```cs
 var mainwindow = GetWindow(this);
```

3.`this.webbrowser` is the control ID of the WPF control ([`FrameworkElement.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx)). By default, this is usually `webbrowser1`.