# How to clear a timer when timer using every 1/10 second

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, winapp

I have a timer running every 1/10 second (`Interval = 100`). It is in an infinte loop because I want to load a site on my `WebBrowser` control and get info into a span ID each time it loads. My problem is if this process runs for a long time, it'll be a memory leak.

In 30 minutes, memory usage can be 800MB or more. How do I prevent my program from continuously using more memory as it runs?

Here is the relevent code. It does not include any of the process creation code yet.

```
private void buttonBid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ID = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxID.Text);
    getItem();
    return;
}

private void getItem()
{
    webBrowser.Url = new Uri("http://www.test.com/?id=" + ID);
    webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
    return;
}

private void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    timerLoad.Start();
    return;
}

private void timerLoad_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var elem = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("product_" + ID);

    textBoxProduct.Text = Convert.ToString(elem.InnerText);

    timerLoad.Dispose();
    timerLoad.Start();
}
```

Comment: I don't think your problem is the timer, it looks like you're properly disposing of your timer.

Comment: 6 questions and 0 accepted answers.

Answer (score 4):

A possible source for memoryleaks is multiple event bindings.

You bind the `DocumentCompleted` event each time the `GetItem` method is invoked.
You should bind the `DocumentCompleted` once, for instance in the constructor of your class.

However if you pressed the button just once, this will not be your main problem.

I would like to recommend [.NET Memory Profiler 4.0](http://memprofiler.com/) to troubleshoot your problem.

Also, I have searched a little bit further and your problem might be in the use of the `WebBrowser` component: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8302933/296526) question.

Comment: +1 to this answer as not unhooking event handlers can cause memory issues sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you should do only once at creation time or so

```
    webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
```

These can be removed. At least I think they serve no purpose and might be problematic

```
    timerLoad.Dispose();
    timerLoad.Start();
```

If I read your code correct the timerLoad.Start(); should be a Stop(); as the Tick loads the document and should then stop working until the next buttonclick, right?

Comment: click button once time and program will running until can't read data from site, program will be stop.