# Browser Console for AOL Desktop?

Tags: debugging, browser, webbrowser-control, aol-desktop

I participate in development of a site that has a significant number of users who view our site through the **[AOL Desktop v9.7](http://daol.aol.com/software/aoldesktop97)** for Windows - which spawns browser windows inside itself. When debugging, I don't have the tooling I would normally be able to invoke (for example Chrome's *Developer Console*; Firebug; MSIE's *F12 developer tools*).

When inside AOL Desktop, I don't appear to have any of these, or anything similar. Is there a developer mode or console I can invoke, unearth?

Comment: From what I can tell, it's just using whatever IE version is currently installed.  Are problems happening with it that aren't happening on the same system's IE?

Comment: @charles in some instances I can debug issues on IE because there's overlap, but sometimes not. So, yes.

Comment: Just got stumbled on this old q because it is featured... @artlung, are you not able to debug JavaScript running in AOL with Visual Studio Debugger (e.g., Express Edition)?

Comment: @Noseratio I don't have Visual Studio Debugger - what I have is website / web applications, not native Windows apps. What would the workflow for that be? If it's usable, please answer as a question? The goal of the question is to give me a Chrome Debugger, MSIE F12 Developer Tools for browser windows resident in AOL Desktop 9.7.

Comment: I'll verify my idea with AOL browser and post it as a solution if it works.

Comment: @artlung, you may want to add "debugging" to the list of the question's tags.

Comment: Here's another [interesting idea](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18289398/1768303), related to the subject. I actually do something similar via `window.external` for the projects where we host WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I meant in my comments, you could just use a very decent JavaScript debugger with manual DOM inspecting features, which comes with Visual Studio (**[EDITED]** including the free edition). With some tricks, it does work for AOL Desktop, too (what an amusing piece of software that is, BTW :) Of course, this is not the same as IE's F12 Tools, it lacks the interactive features like visual DOM tree, CSS tracing etc. But it still allows to step through the code, watch locals and objects, evaluate expressions and access DOM elements. It's an invaluable tool and I use it a lot for projects where we host the WebBrowser control. After all, that's what AOL does, too. Anyway, if you're already familiar with this, just give this post a smile and disregard it. Otherwise, read on :)

---

I tested the following under Win7 SP1 VM with IE9, Visual Studio 2012 Pro (Update3) and the latest AOL Desktop 9.7. **[EDITED]** It also works with the free edition, [Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop), Update3.

The **only major obstacle** was that in about 20 seconds upon entering the debugger, **AOL Browser used to restart itself**, thus disconnecting from the debugger. A workaround for this was to close AOL and **delete** the following files:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\AOL Desktop 9.7\" 
    shellmon.exe
    shellmon.ini
    shellrestart.exe
```

Then, I used the following basic HTML file for debugging purpose (as "debug.html" in the root of localhost):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Debugger Test Page</title>
<script>
function debugPrompt()
{
    if (confirm("debug?"))
    {
        debugger; // breakpoint
        alert("after debugger");
    }
}

document.onkeydown = function()
{
    if (event.altKey && event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 'D'.charCodeAt(0))
    {
        event.cancelBubble = true;
        debugPrompt();
        return;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="debugPrompt()">Debug</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I did exactly:

- Made sure **Script Debugging** is **enabled** in IE settings for both **Internet Explorer** and **Other**:

[image: IE Script Debugging settings]

---

- Made sure **[x] Script** is checked in **VS2012 Debugging Settings, Just-In-Time** section (**[EDITED]** this feature is missing from *VS2012 Express*, but it isn't really important):

[image: VS JIT Debugging Settings]

---

- Ran AOL and navigated to localhost/debug.html.
- Ran Visual Studio and attached to the `aolbrowser.exe` process (with **Script** as the target kind of code), via **Debug/Attach to Process** menu:

[image: VS Attach to Process]

---

- Went back to AOL and hit Ctrl-Alt-D (invokes the "debugger" prompt in my JavaScript listed above). The next thing, I'm in the VS Debugger right at the `debugger;` line of code. At this point, all usual debugging features are available. Note the *Immediate Window* panel and the *Watch1* panel. Also, instead of hard-coding breakpoints with `debugger` keyword as I did, it's possible to use Visual Studio **Solution** panel (once the debugger has been attached) to select one of the JavaScript files loaded by the page and toggle breakpoints interactively.

[image: VS Debugging AOL]

---

Right now, I don't have Visual Studio Express 2012 to verify if the same is possible with it, although I assume it should be. I'll give it a try a bit later.

**[UPDATE]** Almost all of the above applies to the freely available [Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop) w/ [Update3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2835600), with one exception: **Just-In-Time Debugging** option appears to be absent. This is not a show-stopper though, as it is still possible to attach to the running AOL process and debug the currently loaded page the same way.

PS. And thank you for your voluntary bounty offer on an unrelated [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119125/options-for-embedding-chromium-instead-of-ie-webbrowser-control-with-wpf-c), that is a really nice gesture.

Comment: Thanks @Noseratio, I appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone comes here looking for information: the newest 9.8 version of AOL Desktop now includes Chrome's developer tools, which open in a new window when you press F12.