# ActiveX/COM object doing OutputDebugString for use with IE from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, activex

This is specific to Internet Explorer. For certain reasons, I'm unable to use `console.log`. I'm looking for a simple ActiveX object, safe for scripting, that would allow me to log debug output from JavaScript for viewing with the excellent [DbgView tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx). The object should use [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for that.

Then I could simply use it like this:

```
<script>
function debugLog(str)
{
  if (window.debugLogAx === undefined) {
    try { window.debugLogAx = new ActiveXObject("IEDebugTools.Logger"); }
    catch(e) { window.debugLogAx = null; }
  }
  if (window.debugLogAx !== null)
    window.debugLogAx.OutputDebugString(str);
}

debugLog("Hello to DbgView from JavaScript!");
</script>
```

Does such thing exist?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe such ActiveX exists really, but it's quite easy to create such one. Visual Studio, ATL, new object, add new method, and that's all :)

Comment: Yep it's very easy, but then I would need to create an installer package, obtain a code-signing certificate, sign it - all before I can give it to the client facility which I need to troubleshoot. Thought something like this might have existed already, as it sounds like a handy tool to me.