# Throwing error on JS InvokeScript with WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

> "Object doesn't support property or method fireEvent."

I get this error when I try to invoke a script on a `WebBrowser` control with the `InvokeScript();` method.  I'm trying to simulate a click on a link element, and instead I get a `MessageBox` with this error.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the document is fully loaded.

From msdn:

> InvokeScript(String) should not be called before the document that
>   implements it has finished loading. You can detect when a document has
>   finished loading by handling the LoadCompleted event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132.aspx

Comment: I'm pretty confident it is 100% loaded but I'll check again.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the information you provided, we can only make guesses about what's wrong. However, if you're calling a JavaScript function with `InvokeScript`, you can easily figure out the problem yourself: use script debugger and set a breakpoint in your JavaScript code. Here's [how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193387/browser-console-for-aol-desktop/18285339#18285339) (originally for AOL Browser, but it's also a WebBrowser hosting app, so the same technique should work for your app as well).