# Make javascript variable global scope in C# web browser

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control, local-variables, developer-tools

Is there any possibility to read local variable from javascript in c# WebBrowser component? In standard web browser like Chrome I have access to local variables by debugger (Google Developer Tools) and then I can bring variable to global scope like this:

```
window.myGlovalVar = myLocalVar;
```

What possibilities I have in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still can use Visual Studio Debugger to debug JavaScript in a custom application hosting the `WebBrowser` control, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18285339/1768303).

Another option is to type and execute `WebBrowser.InvokeScript` (WPF) or `WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript` (WinForms) directly from the debugger's QuickWatch window.

E.g., set a variable:

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("execScript", "window.myGlovalVar = myLocalVar")
```

Query it later (will return the value `myLocalVar` remembered above):

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "window.myGlovalVar")
```