# How to go about implementing a webkit based windows application?

Tags: javascript, .net, windows, visual-studio, webkit

This is a bit of an open-ended question, since I am just starting out on the project.

Problem: I have clients who cannot install web-browsers on their machines, and are stuck with IE6. The app we are selling them is a web-based app using a lot of javascript and jquery.

Solution: Implement a windows application that has a web-browser control based on webkit (since the regular webbrowser control is not going to support javascript and jquery), which loads the app.

I started doing research, and I found 2 controls: 
https://code.google.com/p/open-webkit-sharp/
and
http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

I started off with the second one, and tried the sample app they built, only to discover that the version of webkit they used is really old and doesn't run our app right.

So my current solution is to compile webkit myself and include the newer version in the control and see how that works out.

Since this is a time-sensitive issue I thought I'd also ask for the experience of StackOverflow at the same time I am going down my route, to see if there is a simpler solution, or if there are any libraries or pre-built controls I could use that I missed in my search?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Check out this: [Options for embedding Chromium instead of IE WebBrowser control with WPF/C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119125/options-for-embedding-chromium-instead-of-ie-webbrowser-control-with-wpf-c)

Comment: Thank you! That was quite helpful. I managed to implement open-webkit-sharp yesterday with moderate success, but will be looking to shift to awesomium based on what I read!

Comment: Glad it helped. The most recommended framework was actually [CEF](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/), although Awesomium may indeed suit you better, depending on your needs and budget.