# Embed Chrome Extension in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Chrome now supports offline apps. Is there anyway to embed them in a Winforms application? I know there are ways to embed [Chrome instead of IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119125/options-for-embedding-chromium-instead-of-ie-webbrowser-control-with-wpf-c)

Comment: So, embed Chrome and let it run the application?

Comment: I tried running the app directly from its installation directory in Chrome. It doesn't work