# google map is not showing in vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, google-maps

i have written a simple vb application to show the google map . But it  is not working properly.

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim City As String = TextBox1.Text
    Try
        Dim queryAddress As New StringBuilder
        queryAddress.Append("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=")

        If TextBox1.Text = String.Empty Then
            queryAddress.Append(City + " , " & " + ")
        End If
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(queryAddress.ToString())
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("UnAvailable")
    End Try

End Sub
```

when simple click on button it shows a place . but when i give something input in the textbox and search it, shows

"You seem to be using an unsupported browser. Old browsers can put your security at risk, are slow and don't work with   newer Google Maps features. To access Google Maps, you'll need to update to  a modern browser." 
Any suggestion ? it spoiled my whole day.
thank you

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a Chromium-based web component. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119125/options-for-embedding-chromium-instead-of-ie-webbrowser-control-with-wpf-c).

Comment: No, what I mean is using a Chromium-based web browser component in your .Net program.  Clearly, Google Maps thinks the component you're currently using is outdated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank for valuable response... i did like removing some parts..

```
If TextBox1.Text = String.Empty Then
   queryAddress.Append(City)
End If
```