# Running a web client inside a WPF wrapper

Tags: wpf, webclient, web-controls, partial-trust

We have a browser-based client that talks to our cloud-based service.  The client does fairly vanilla things, such as handling user input, and displaying data from the server in HighStock (a browser-based js charting app).

A potential customer wants to use our product, but it has to be WPF, and run in a sandbox as a partial trust app. Our app would be able to send and get data from our app and our server, but that is all.  There is no way we could afford to rewrite the app as a native WPF app.

Is there a way to run our existing app using a web control inside a WPF wrapper?

If so, is it true that this approach would have, from their point of view, the same level of security as a native WPF app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options for browser controls - the native one (WebBrowser class), and you can also embed Chromium within WPF (see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119125/options-for-embedding-chromium-instead-of-ie-webbrowser-control-with-wpf-c))