# Which Browser for a Touch-Enabled WPF Application?

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, touch, dotnetbrowser

I looked at this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119125/options-for-embedding-chromium-instead-of-ie-webbrowser-control-with-wpf-c) searching for a Web Browser to embed into a touch-enabled WPF application (on Windows 8 or 10).

I need to support manipulations (meaning be able to zoom, pane, rotate with touch events).

If possible, I would like also to support one of the game frameworks being either Adobe Flash, Unity or Web GL. Or a really working HTML 5 support with touch events.

Investigations performed so far:
 - I have tried Awesomium, but I have too many issues with it. I created two questions on their forums two months ago and still don't have any reply.

- Also, I tried CEF, but it crashes when the main application is stopped. Also, it does NOT support touch events.
- Obviously, I also tried the default WebBrowser, but this one is an ActiveX control so it does not support manipulations.

So, I am about to test dotnetbrowser and EO.WebBrowser. Both require licenses which is less attractive to me but anyway if this the only way to go.
However, none of these browser implementations describe if they support a touch
interface.

Do you have any input on this issue?

Thanks a lot for your help
Best regards
Christophe

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it work by using a wrapper above CEF called Xilium.CEFGlue.
I could dive into the source code and add the touch support myself.

It works pretty well.
Thanks a lot for your help.
Christophe