# How to use chrome instead of internet explorer as a browser in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, browser, maps, version

I'm implementing a map that will locate the latitude and longitude of a place and I want to change the cons string key bit in setting up a browser like chrome. In this code telling me that it uses internet explorer and I want to change it to chrome.

```
   private void SetWebBrowserVersion(int ie_version)
     {
        const string key64bit =
            @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\" +
            @"MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";
        const string key32bit =
            @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\" +
            @"FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";
        string app_name = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;

        SetRegistryDword(key64bit, app_name, ie_version);
     }

       DisplayMap(){
       //internet explorer
       SetWebBrowserVersion(11001);
     }


     private void SetRegistryDword(string key_name,
     string value_name, int value)
     {
        RegistryKey key =
            Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(key_name, true);
        if (key == null)
            key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(key_name,
                RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
        key.SetValue(value_name, value, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        key.Close();
      }
```

Comment: `I want to change it to chrome.` You can't.

Comment: Maybe try [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Options for embedding Chromium instead of IE WebBrowser control with WPF/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119125/options-for-embedding-chromium-instead-of-ie-webbrowser-control-with-wpf-c)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with WebBrowser.

You may want to try [BrowseEmAll.Gecko](https://bitbucket.org/positionfixed/browseemall.gecko/src/master/) for Firefox or [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/) for Chrome integration to .NET applications.