# Windows phone memory allocation graph

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7

The memory usage graph from the vs attached seems confusing to  me , the graph shows the memory sage as about 100mb but the reading below the graph shows the retained allocations at the end is 5MB . doesn't make sense to me

[image: Screen Shot of the graph]

Comment: The profiler only counts managed objects. If the numbers don't add up with the graph, it means you're consuming memory with native objects (probably pictures). And yes, that makes the profiler pretty much useless to diagnose this kind of memory issue

Comment: Thanks kooKiz .. i am using a webbrowser control in a page  which loads a youtube video ,, and i have multiple pages  of similar kind , could it be the issue with the memory leak in webbrowser control .. is the issue in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302933/how-to-get-around-the-memory-leak-in-the-net-webbrowser-control  .. also applicable for wp