# Memory leak in windows web browser using VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms, memory-leaks

I have built a basic web browser using vb, say like IE6, where I don't have tabbed windows. 
I have option of creating new window.

When I open one window and navigate to the Google page, the task manager shows 33,546 K memory usage.
On opening second and navigate to gmail, it shows 54,786K.
On opening third and go to facebook, it shows 70,191K.
But when I close any one of them, say like facebook, it is only releasing around 4 MB memory and task manager shows 66,672K. on closing second, it shows 62,890K.

What I actually want to happen is when I close facebook, memory usage should go back to around 54,000K.
I am very new to programming VB, and don't even know if what is actually happening is memory leak or not. But anyway, is there anyway to make what i want happen, that windows release their maximum memory?
Do help.

I am using dispose method to close the windows. There were solutions which asked to create two separate applications and called the browser windows in parent and there take care of events and memory based on some method i wasn't able to understand.
If that's the way then can someone point me to a tutorial where I can learn how to do that?

Comment: This can't possibly be diagnosed with only the given information.

Comment: Thanks and Sorry if information is less. Tell me what information is needed and i will provide that. @Jonathon

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get around the memory leak in the .NET Webbrowser control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302933/how-to-get-around-the-memory-leak-in-the-net-webbrowser-control)